# issue with UWP CreateFileAsync

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I have an issue using CreateFileAsync method from UWP API in C++/CX.
Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
    create_task(folder->CreateFileAsync(destination_file, Windows::Storage::CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists)).
        then(
            [this](StorageFile^ dest_file)
            {
                //do something here
            });
```

The call of CreateFileAsync seem to be successful as my files are created in the proper place.
However, the code inside my lambda function (`//do something here`) is never executed.

Would anyone could explain me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> The call of CreateFileAsync seem to be successful as my files are created in the proper place. However, the code inside my lambda function (//do something here) is never executed.

I could not reproduce your issue in my side.You have used `create_task` to execute `CreateFileAsync` async method. The `.then` block can be regarded as callback function. And it will be executed after `CreateFileAsync`finished. You can write the following code to verify that it is executed.

```
create_task(folder->CreateFileAsync("test.jpg", Windows::Storage::CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists)).
    then(
        [this](StorageFile^ dest_file)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"excuted------->");
});
```

For more you could refer to [Asynchronous programming in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps).

Comment: Thanks, actually the command was never executed. I had to refactor my code to get around this issue. still don't know what happened.

Comment: That's not helpful. The OP already determined, that the code in question doesn't execute. Providing an alternative to determine that the code doesn't run fails to address the issue.